# Using an interface method for an object of one data type in an array of a different data type? Java

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, interface

So my problem is that I have a class called `GeometricFigure2` which holds fields such as `width` and `height`. I have an interface called `SidedObject` which holds a method to display how many sides a figure has

```
public interface SidedObject
{
    public void displaySides();
}
```

I have two subclasses called `Square2` and `Triangle2` which extend `GeometricFigure2` and implement `SidedObject`. Both classes contain the `displaySides()` method which looks like:

```
public void displaySides()
{
   System.out.println("The square has 4 sides.");
}
```

Finally I have a class called `UseGeometricFigure2` which uses both subclasses. I create an array with a type of `GeometricFigure2` which is used to hold two `Square2` objects and two `Triangle2` objects:

```
GeometricFigure2[] geoRef = new GeometricFigure2[4];
    geoRef[0] = new Square2();
    geoRef[1] = new Square2();
    geoRef[2] = new Triangle2();
    geoRef[3] = new Triangle2();
```

I then create a for loop to iterate through the array and call the `displaySides()` method for each object in the array:

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    geoRef[i].displaySides();
}
```

The problem is when I try to compile it gives me a "Cannot find symbol" error. It is looking for `displaySides()` in the `GeometricFigure2` class which is the array type. How do I correctly call the `displaySides()` method in this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three choices:

1. Have `GeometricFigure2` implement your `SidedObject` interface.
2. Declare your array as type `SidedObject[]` instead of `GeometricFigure2[]`.
3. Cast your array variables to `SidedObject`:
   `((SidedObject) geoRef[i]).displaySides();`

Comment: The first option works best for me as I have other methods in the GeometricFigure2 class. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the `displaySides()` method from `SideObject` to work with instances of `GeometricFigure2` you would need to modify `GeometricFigure2` to implement `SidedObject`.